# Why this for loop ends in the second index?

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, dev-c++

I wrote a program that it's duty is to read 20 numbers from user and put them in a list, after that it prints the value in array from bottom to starting point.

But program stops exactly after reading second value from input.

Source code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 20
int main(void)
{
    int numbers[N];
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        scanf("%i", &numbers[i]);
    }

    for(i=N;i<0;i--)
    {
        printf("%i", numbers[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I use *Dev-C++ 5.6.3* as my IDE and *TDM-GCC 4.8.1* as my compiler. But I don't know exactly that is this an IDE related issue or not.

Comment: Don't you mean `i>0` for your second loop?

Comment: `scanf("%i", numbers[i]);` ==> `scanf("%i", &numbers[i]);`

Comment: Did your code have a `&` or did it not? Please don't change the question.

Comment: Voting to close this as simple typo(s).

Comment: @WeatherVane No It has &, I forgot to add it, but know question is ok.

Comment: Try adding a single space to the start of the format string. And add code to check the return value of `scanf()`.

Comment: regarding this line: `for(i=N;i<0;i--)`   1) in C, an array offset is from 0 to number of elements in array-1.  the first expression should be: `i-(n-1)` 2) the variable `i` will only be `<0` at loop termination, the code really wants to stay in the loop as long as `i` >= 0  so the second expression should be: `i >= 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the loop to count downwards, then this loop

```
for(i=N;i<0;i--)
```

starts at the wrong index, and fails the test condition. It should be

```
for(i = N - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want your second loop to count down, then

```
 for(i=N;i<0;i--)
```

should be

```
 for(i=N;i>0;i--)
```

or the loop will not execute, as `i<0` is not true to start with.

and, as @WeatherVane pointed out in the comments:

```
scanf("%i", numbers[i]);
```

should be

```
scanf("%i", &numbers[i]);
```

as you need to pass a pointer to the integer you wish to fill in with the number that `scanf` returns.

Answer (score 3):

There is some issue with the given below for loop.

```
for(i=N;i<0;i--)
{
    printf("%i", numbers[i]);
}
return 0;
```

If you Want to print the array from bottom to starting point.
You can make some changes in the for loop.

## Changes :

1- Change in loop while assigning the value to i :
   `i = N-1` ->  as the size of array is 20 and array index starts with 0.
   it will go 19 to 0 to print all 20 data values.

2- changes in the condition check in for loop : 
   `i >= 0` as we printing the reverse array.

Correct for loop should be

```
for(i = N-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    printf("%i", numbers[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

for(i=N-1;i>=0;i--)

For n items in an array, last index will be n-1. you need to iterate from n-1 index to 0th index.

Answer (score 1):

second loop must be 
 `for(i=N;i>=0;i--)`
so index will be from 19 to 0 ( 20 number )

Try This

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 20
int main(void)
{
    int numbers[N];
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        scanf("%i", &numbers[i]);
    }

    for(i = N ; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        printf("%i ", numbers[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 20
int main(void)
{
    int numbers[N];
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        scanf("%i", &numbers[i]);
    }

    for(i = N - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        printf("%i ", numbers[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Remember that scanf always uses pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Your second loop's condition, "i<0", is false to begin with. It should be "i > -1". You also need to make sure that the first time printf is called with index 19 and not 20. That is why I use pre decrement operator -- i.

```
for(i = N; i > -1; )
{
    printf("%i\n", numbers[--i])
};
```